# install NTFS system checks?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

I have a external hard drive and I'm checking it with the `Disk Utility`. However, it gave me an error says

```
** No NTFS file system checks have been implemented yet.
```

How can I install one?

Answer (score 1):

OS X supports the option to read NTFS-formatted drives, but has not supported writing to these drives. Therefore, the use of a third-party driver such as Paragon NTFS or Tuxera NTFS has been required for those seeking full NTFS support; however, OS X does support writing to NTFS, but this feature is just not enabled by default.

1. Enable NTFS option via Terminal *(I am not going to document this, as I highly do not recommend using this option at all, unless you are aware of the problems this will lead to)*
2. Download and install [SL-NTFS](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33603/sl-ntfs) which is an NFTS writing preference for your Mac. Works on Mac OS X 10.6+ **(FREE)**
3. Install [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html), though this is not my favourite option. It's a little slow and can cause compatibility issues with anything after Mac OS X 10.6. Some users report it working flawlessly. I personally think it's write capability is a little slow. Touch and go. **(FREE)**
4. [Paragon NTFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) which is approx **$20**, is the entry-level of paid software version. I have used this for quite a while and never had a problem. Works on anything from Mac OS X **10.6.x** → **10.8.x**
5. [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) costs approx **$32** and does everything that Paragon NTFS does. I use this one now, because it built upon the NTFS-3G option I mentioned earlier. I personally believe it works the best as I have never had an issue with it to date, but then I have used all options (*aside #2*) and found no issues with any of them.

To solve your enquiry, either NTFS-3G, Paragon or Tuxera will all enable you to use Disk Utility to check the drive, format the drive, etc etc. The picture below is from my system.

**NOTE:** I am not saying SL-NTFS will not do what you want, I just have not tested it.

[image]